# ExcelLite can not read russian characters

Tags: .net, silverlight-5.0

When I read Excel file by using ExcelLite library from Silverlight, russian characters don't read. Instead, create a line like this:
,& #"", $ !# " -"
How can I transcode, or bring them to the required mean or to solve the problem in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved:

https://excellite.codeplex.com/workitem/270

To support Unicode, I think should modify the method GetStringUnicode(byte[] value) in ConversionHelper.cs

```
public static String GetStringUnicode(byte[] value)
{
   return new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetString(value, 0, value.Length);
}
```